# Ubuntu newbie needs network and routing help

Tags: networking, routing

I've installed 14.04 server, configured DNS and DHCP for my local network which all seems to be working OK. This is connected to eth1. I've installed plex which I need to connect to my drobo where all my media is stored. This is where my problems begin. The drobo is connected to a second interface, eth2 with a direct cable, no routers, switch etc. And I can't seem to reach it at all.

Comment: Is the Drobo connected directly to the Ubuntu Sever?

Comment: Hi Alex, That was quick :-)  Yes the drobo is the only thing connected to eth2 and everything else is on eth1.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu Server acting as a router?

Comment: did you use right cable? for direct connection you have to have special cable.
also: check if your device have static ips set on that direct link

Comment: personal note, I installed a server edition for my very first linux use. I ended up adding the GUI later just make my life a bit less complex. it helped me with the learning curve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Alex, the drobo is just a data store, nothing more.  Fih, The cable is correct. Basically what I've done is replace Windows server 2008 with 14.04 LTS. The server works perfectly under windows.  wlraider70, yes, I agree. I installed the GUI desktop last night.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the drobo is DHCP querying for getting its IP address, which the server doesn't service as it's on the "wrong" interface.
You can configure your server's DHCP server to offer addresses on that interface as well, but probably it needs to be a different network for the drobo+server link. Your server would then also need to act as gateway between the two networks, if other hosts on the first network need to "see" the drobo or vice versa.

Comment: Hi Ralph, the drobo is manually set with a static ip, 192.168.98.2 in this case. eth2 is also manually configured at 192.168.98.1.  There doesn't need to be any pass through traffic from eth1 to eth2, I just need to mount the shares from the drobo via eth2 (192.168.98.1).

Comment: You may be past this, but: If, after "ping -n 192.168.98.2" on the server, there is not an "arp -n" entry for drobo on the server, then it's likely a cabling issue. E.g., does it  requires a cross-over cable for these interfaces? (or an intermediate switch). If there is an "arp -n" entry, then it's likely a higher level issue, e.g. routing or DNS.

Comment: Hi Ralph,  I know the physical side of all the connections are fine.  Up until  3 days ago the box was running Win 2008 server, exactly the same hardware setup with everything working fine.

Comment: Right. So I would focus on DNS firts, becauseAfaik, Ubuntu does not service DNS to external interfaces

Comment: (ignore the above)
Right. So I would focus on DNS first, because the drobo might get upset if its DNS is "broken". I assume you use "tcpdump" to monitor the interface.   
Then it'd be a matter of ensuring that DNS is serviced properly. There are a number of avenues depending on your set up, though afaik, NetworkManager doesn't service DNS to external interfaces by default, and I have rather chosen to disable its DNS handling and use a separate "dnsmasq" for this. Though, this is only valid if DNS is your issue.